# Selecting randomly a random variable out of N

Tags: distributions, random-variable, mixture-distribution

I have $N$ well defined random variables (each with their average $\mu_i$ and standard deviation $\sigma_i$). The outcome of an experiment can be the value of one of the random variables. For each variable, I do know their probability $p_i$ of being selected.

Is it possible to determine the standard deviation and the average of the experiment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data follows a [mixture distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_distribution), with probability density function

$$ f(x) = \sum_k p_k \, f_k(x; \mu_k, \sigma_k) $$

where $f_k$ are probability density functions of distributions of the variables parametrized by $\mu_k,\sigma_k$ and $p_k$ are the mixing proportions. The mean and variance of such distribution are

$$
\operatorname{E}[X] = \mu = \sum_k p_k \mu_k \\
\operatorname{E}[(X - \mu)^2] = \sigma^2 = \sum_k p_k((\mu_k - \mu)^{2} + \sigma_k^2) 
$$